# How can I get last row/column using jquery bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a fluid container format. In that I created a panel and the panel has an id. I keep on adding data to the container in `<row><col>data</row></col>` format.

I was wondering if it is possible to get the last row and column for bootstrap grid in a panel too?

```
<div class="panel-body" id="test">
div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                A1
                            </div>
                        </div>

div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                A2
                            </div>
                        </div>

</div>
```

Can I use some version of `$("#test").last("row")`  or `$("#test").last("row").last("col")`

Comment: There are two `<div>`'s which miss the starting `<`, is this a copy/paste error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery provides an entire selection of supported attribute selectors. If you are sure that the class names will be exactly `col-lg-12` and `row` then the other answers will work. If however, the columns could be different such as `col-xs-4`, then you could use the *Attribute Contains Prefix Selector*.

According to the jQuery documentation this selector:

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value either equal to a given string or starting with that string followed by a hyphen (-).

```
/* 
 * Selects the last item in the table where the class value = "col" or
 * begins with "col-..."
 */
$('#test div[class|="col"]:last');

/* 
 * Selects the last item in the table where the class value = "row" or
 * begins with "row-..."
 */
$('#test div[class|="row"]:last');
```

**Reference:** [Attribute Contains Prefix Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/)

**Reference:** [Complete List of jQuery Attribute Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

**DEMO:** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/YwZ57/)

Comment: generic and more useful, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".row").last().find(".col-lg-12").last();
```

[image]

***[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JHG2C/)***

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery [.last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/)

Try this :

```
$(".row").last().find(".col-lg-12").last();
```

Comment: How is that different than my answer? =D

Comment: @Code Maverick: Sorry i did't see your answer when i post my answer. (I think it's due to my internet issue).

Comment: No worries. I figured as much.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#test div.row:last") // for last row
$("#test div.col-lg-12:last") //for last column
```